# Setup Individual User Storage

Tags: active-directory, storage, windows-server-2012

Does anyone know where I can search for (and the terms to use) or have a link to how I would setup a personal user drive/storage for my Active Directory users?

Also, how do I go about getting this drive mapped automatically when they login?

Lastly and slightly less important question is if a Mac can take advantage of this drive automatically based on login?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

["Folder Redirection."](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781907%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Typically, you'll define their user profile location as on a server somewhere, say `\\server\Users\%username%\` (where that folder tree is on a partition for all your user's directories) and everything that goes under their `Documents and Settings` or `Users` folder gets synced to that location.  Those options can be set by GPO automagically, or by hand, under the <kbd>Profile</kbd> tab for the user's account in `ADUC`.

Making Mac or Linux users part of this is... a PITA, to say the least.

Answer (score 4):

> Does anyone know where I can search for (and the terms to use) or have a link to how I would setup a personal user drive/storage for my Active Directory users?

You use a SMB file share for this and use NTFS permissions so that only a specific user (and usually admins) have access to their specific folder

You can use the File System Resource Manager to set quotas and file-type screens.

> Also, how do I go about getting this drive mapped automatically when they login?

Group Policy

> Lastly and slightly less important question is if a Mac can take advantage of this drive automatically based on login?

Sure, just configure it to map the drive over SMB or CIFS at logon.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify on the last point that MDMarra said... To set the Mac to auto mount on logon, do the following:

From Finder click Go > Connect To Server

Type smb://IPOFSERVER/home/username and then connect.

After it is connected, open System Preferences > Click on User Accounts > Login Items

Drag the mounted drive from the desktop into Login Items.